# Get date from timestamp in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I would like to display my timestamp in the front as the date.
I tried several methods but none worked.
here is the code:`

```
formulaire.addEventListener('submit', posteValidation);
/**
 *  Fonction pour ajouter une publication dans le serveur
 * @param {Event} event 
 */
const addPosteServeur = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(formulaire.checkValidity()){
        let data = {
            id_user: 1,
            timestamps: date.getTime(),
            text : textPoste.value
        }
        let response = await fetch('/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        });
        if(response.ok){
            addPosteClient({
                id_user: 1,
                timestamps: date.getTime(),
                text: textPoste.value
            });

            textPoste.value = '';
        }
    }
}
formulaire.addEventListener('submit', addPosteServeur);`
```

Thanks

Comment: what exactly do you want to show? what value does date in your code have?

Comment: How is this code relevant to your question? We need to see the `addPosteClient` function and how it displays the timestamp. And what do node.js or express have to do with any of this?

Comment: Currently it is a sequence of timestamp numbers. I want to convert it to date in addPosteClient()

Answer (score 1):

to get the date as timestamp in Node.js simply do `Date.now()`. If you want to get the date as string, you can use `new Date().toUTCString()` I suggest you to read the Date API that can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date